# Es posible hacer un Join con una tabla vacía?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

me gustaría saber lo siguiente: Quiero hacer un Stored procedure para obtener una consulta que me muestre datos de 3 tablas generadas por query, la consulta es la siguiente:

```
Select t1.RecordDate1, t1.RecordType1, t1.EntryTime1, t1.ExitTime1, t2.RecordType2, t2.EntryTime2,
t2.ExitTime2, t3.RecordType3, t3.EntryTime3, t3.ExitTime3,
(Select timediff(((select ADDTIME(t1.TotalHours,t3.TotalHours))), t2.TotalHours)) as TotalHours
From
(
    Select CONCAT(Name,' ',LastName) as Name,
    Records.UserID,
    RecordDate as RecordDate1, 
    RecordType as RecordType1,
    EntryTime as EntryTime1,
    ExitTime as ExitTime1, 
    TotalHours
    From Records 
    inner join Users
    inner join RecordType
    on Users.UserID = Records.UserID and Records.RecordTypeID = RecordType.RecordTypeID
    Where Records.UserID = 1 AND Records.RecordTypeID = 1 AND RecordDate Between '2022-02-21' and '2022-02-24'
) t1 
inner join
(
    Select CONCAT(Name,' ',LastName) as Name,
    Records.UserID,
    RecordDate as RecordDate3, 
    RecordType as RecordType3,
    EntryTime as EntryTime3,
    ExitTime as ExitTime3, 
    TotalHours
    From Records 
    inner join Users
    inner join RecordType
    on Users.UserID = Records.UserID and Records.RecordTypeID = RecordType.RecordTypeID
    Where Records.UserID = 1 AND Records.RecordTypeID = 3 AND RecordDate Between '2022-02-21' and '2022-02-24'
) t3 
inner join
(
    Select CONCAT(Name,' ',LastName) as Name,
    Records.UserID,
    RecordDate as RecordDate2, 
    RecordType as RecordType2,
    EntryTime as EntryTime2,
    ExitTime as ExitTime2, 
    TotalHours
    From Records 
    inner join Users
    inner join RecordType
    on Users.UserID = Records.UserID and Records.RecordTypeID = RecordType.RecordTypeID
    Where Records.UserID = 1 AND Records.RecordTypeID = 2 AND RecordDate Between '2022-02-21' and '2022-02-24'
) t2
on t1.RecordDate1 = t2.RecordDate2 and t1.RecordDate1 = t3.RecordDate3 order by t1.RecordDate1;
```

El query funciona cuando en el periodo de fechas las tablas devuelven al menos un registro, pero si hay algún caso en el que alguna tabla no devuelva nada entonces toda la consulta no me devuelve nada ya que se estaría haciendo un Join con una tabla vacía.

Así que mi pregunta es: Hay alguna manera de hacer que, en caso de que alguna tabla sea vacía, poner sus correspondientes datos en Null?, o en su defecto debo reformular mi consulta?

Espero su ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Te refieres a usar `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas como funcionan los JOINS, no solo existe inner join

Answer (score 2):

Cuando haces un `INNER JOIN` el enlace lo hace entre las columans de las tablas y te va a devolver los datos que le pidas en la sentencia `SELECT` que pueden ser de las dos tablas, la única manera que te devuelva null es las columnas que pongas en la `SELECT` estén vacías todas o te pudede devolver algún null en un registro porque en ese registro en particular no existe dato alguno